# Seagate external drive freeze problem

Tags: debian, external-hdd

I've recently bought a Seagate STBU1000200 1TB external usb hard drive. The first thing I did was to delete the NTFS partition and create an ext4 one with Gparted. Ever since, I'm facing strange freeze issues; usually during reading or copying to the drive. The hard drive will freeze (or crash) and will automatically unmount. `dmesg` output follows:

```
[15051.558012] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[15051.558017] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[15051.558024] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 36 ae f0 00 00 f0 00
[15051.558036] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 3583728
[15051.558089] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[15051.558094] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[15051.558102] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 36 af e0 00 00 10 00
[15051.558114] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 3583968
[15051.722298] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[15051.722338] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[15056.558280] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
[15056.558287] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 121667584
[15056.558289] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[15056.558291] JBD2: I/O error detected when updating journal superblock for sdb1-8.
```

Any ideas? I'm running Debian 6.0 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem for quite some time with Seagate-branded (FreeAgent) drives on Debian 6 AMD64.  If I use either the "Safely Remove Drive" or "Unmount" option, I will (at best) get crash reports on any terminal logged in as root and a GUI notification of a crash.  At worst (which seems to be the norm recently) the system will hard-crash.  The mouse pointer won't move and even the SysRQ keys won't do anything.
   These are various sizes (I've had some 500GB, 1TB, 2TB) do this.  They are NTFS formatted and have been checked for errors on Windows (and found no errors).  I can unplug them without doing the "Safe Remove" and I don't have any problem.  I always leave them sitting for 10-15 seconds doing nothing before I unplug them and that seems to do the trick.  The only common feature I've noticed is that it seems to always be Seagate drives (FreeAgent model).  I don't have the problem with other manufacturer drives or SD cards, etc.  So I've just trained myself to not use the "Safe Remove" option with them.

Comment: Same issue with a Seagate drive (8TB) 5 years later on Debian 64-bit. The difference being that it's an internal drive and it always hard-crashes the system (mouse pointer won't move etc.). Everyone's warnings against Seagate seem well-founded tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Install smartmontools (sudo apt-get install smartmontools), then check disk health with:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

Examine the output, post here if you want.  You should also run an extended offline test:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdb
```

Wait for it to complete and check results, most likely your drive is failing, and you need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Run `chkfs` on the ext4 partition and see what you get.
2. If you run into troubles, try `chkfs` on another Linux box and see if the issue persist.
3. Last resort: try to wipe out the whole drive and recreate an NTFS partition on the drive and see if the issue persists.

By trying this, we will make sure that it is not a problem with the drive FAT or your Debian kernel.
If this didn't work, I am sorry to tell you that your HDD may have become faulty and it is just the coincidence that this happened after you formated it.

Comment: Thanks, fsck didn't return any errors. But the drive hasn't been crashing ever since. I will keep it mounted for a couple of hours and see how it goes. Do you think I broke T&C of grandee by formating or I could return it?

Comment: It is good that `fsck` didn't find errors and it stopped crashing.
May be it has corrected a problem that he found or may be not.
Just keep using it as you say.
For T&C I have no idea, may be you can just reformat it to its original state and try returning it.